# RegEx - exclude specified list of strings that contain the string to match

Tags: regex, full-text-search, notepad++

exclude specified list of strings that contain the string to match

i.e.

match any string that contains SON - i.e. SON, SONAR, JSON, SON-O-GRAM, _SON

while at the same time exclude GRANDSON and SONY and any other strings put in the list

I cannot achieve both at the same time. Is it possible to somehow prioritize the exclusion group over the match pattern?

I am looking for simple solution that would work in NP++ and similar ctrl+f searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to achive this is by using the Control Verbs (*SKIP) (*FAIL).

First you would provide what you don't want to match as what to match and tell the system to Skip those but match in the rest of the text.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/TfnrWQ/1)

Given your example you would end up with a pattern like this:

Paste in Notepad++ without starting and ending delimiters ie /

```
/\b(?:GRANDSON|SONY)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S*SON\S*/
```

\S*SON\S* : Meaning match any non space character 0 or more times, then the letters SON and any non space character 0 or more times again.

Change that to [a-z_]*SON[a-z_]* etc if you want to be specific with what you want to match, ie alpha or underscore on each side

In Notepad++ Make sure you have selected the "**Regular expression**" Search Mode before testing.